# Is it possible to set the value of a Geometry Node string using Python

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need to set Geometry Nodes strings to certain dates so that I can then create Text objects with those dates. I know how to get the current date using Python. Is it possible to use a Python script to determine the value of a string in the Geometry Nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set the values of geometry nodes using a python script that looks something like this:

```
    import bpy

    bpy.data.node_groups['Geometry Nodes'].nodes['String'].string = "Test"
```

This sets the string value of the node named "String" in the node group named "Geometry Nodes" to Test.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. I assume there is no way to execute a Python script directly in the node tree (so this has to be in a separate python file)?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no way to execute a script directly in the node tree, you'd have to add a script in the text editor window and run it manually. Hopefully one day there will be some kind of script node.

Comment: I tried this, but geometry nodes didn't trigger an update. Solved it by running "bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()" twice, so the mesh gets recaluclated